# LinearLayout does not appear

Tags: java, android, layout, android-layout

Why can not I see the last LinearLayout?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/bg" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="2dp"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" .../>

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        // TableRows created dynamically
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>`
```

**Edited:** android:layout_gravity="bottom"

Comment: Why donot you go for Relativelayout with alignparentBottom=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thing would happen because U have put the Child First Liner layout and scroll View might be contaning the more space compare to the screen so the last child of this liner layout has no more space for their View .

For the Solution u may take the Relative layout For this or put the layout_weight for all the child View as per  your Requirement . i think the last option is batter for u .

Comment: RelativeLayout was better, but you answer helps me

Comment: use the layout_weight for the linerLayout ..to learn about this please refer this   [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not nearly as comfortable with android layouts as I would like but I think it may be because of what's inside your ScrollView. You set ScrollView's parameters to wrap_content which means it will be as large as its children require. But the nested TableLayout uses fill_parent so ScrollView "inherits" that and fills up the entire screen. Once again, I make no guarantees that this is actually correct.

Comment: I just wanna make a menu with buttons at the bottom

Comment: Im using fill_parent only to the width

Answer (score 1):

Because most probably the content above last linear layout is so large that there is not enough space left for the last linear layout out and it's button to appear